# Angular firestore get value of observable

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

i'm downloading data form my firestore database. Afterwards i want to iterate through my Observable and get one specific value.

To do so i tried the following:

```
interface Note{
imageUrl: string;
title: string;
body: string;
titledesc: string;
imgalt: string;
imgdesc: string;
imgtitle: string;
authorId: string;

}
```

here are my variables:

```
  notesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Note>;
  notes: Observable<Note[]>;
```

and here is my method:

```
getAuthorData = function(blog: string){
this.notesCollection = this.afs.collection('/Blogs', ref =>{
  return ref.where('title','==', blog)

}).valueChanges()
this.notesCollection.subscribe( data => {
    console.log(data.authorId)
});
}
```

the logs always shows undefined

Comment: So your collection string looks like it is probably wrong. With Firestore it usually isn’t a path. Try collection(‘blogs’) or collection(‘Blogs’) and let me know if that changes anything.

Comment: Also valueChanges returns an observable so that would be what is assigned to notes, not notesCollection.